# Easel.js canvas not updating

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I have the following code in which I am trying to draw a rectangle using createjs

```
function Game(canvas) {
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas),
        character = new createjs.Shape();

    this.init = function (x, y, angle) {
       character.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(x, y, 100, 100);
       character.rotation = angle;
       stage.addChild(character);
       stage.update();
    }

}

Game.run = function (canvas) {
    var game = new Game(canvas),
        startX = 400,
        startY = 200,
        startAngle = 45;
    game.init(startX, startY, startAngle);

}
```

But it doesn't display anything. Have I missed something obvious?

[jsfiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/384CB/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rotation is not working like you probably think it is.

The origin of your 'character' is at `0,0` - and not at the `x,y` of the `drawRect` call. By rotating it you probably move it out of your canvas/sight.

Change the `startX` and `startY` to 100 and see part of your cube appear! (in the fiddle)

If you want the rotation to be applied only on the cube relative to its own top-left corner. You should call drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100) to draw it and change the `x` and `y` properties of `character` to move the square.

Comment: Removing the rotation makes it display and changing the x and y properties corrects the issue. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You usually want to move the coordinates of your shape in which you always draw your graphics starting from the origin (0,0).

So instead of

```
character.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(x, y, 100, 100);
```

You should have something like

```
character.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
character.x = x;
character.y = y;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/384CB/1/)